# What the Frick is "Hollywood Sleek"?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, images, page-layout

Okay so I have a client who ALWAYS asks for things in a very vague manner but absolutely and categorically refuses to divulge more into their idea(s).

So recently they sent me an email saying they needed a webpage doing with some graphics but they want them to look "Hollywood Sleek"  I asked what they said, "You know, like ballin'"

Now I know...I know, a lot of you may say drop them as a client as it isnt worth the hassle. That being said they are a very good client, always pay my fee on time, weekly work and to be fair they are great apart from when I need to communicate ideas with them.

I even sent them over my standard "What do you need doing" template so they could at least give me a brief thats more than half a sentence, but alas, they have no want to fill that in, they simply always say things like above.

So...apart from lipstick and makeup (which is all that really turns up when searching for "Hollywood Sleek" online...Does anyone have a clue what that means?

Your help is both appreciated and leaves me with hope of a future without killer robots.

Thanks

Comment: No one here has *absolutely any* experience with this client.... I mean zero, none, not a shred.... so I can't possibly see how anyone here would be in a better position to interpret what *that client* means when they use slang. The problem with colloquialisms and "trendy" language is.. it means different things to different people. If you don't even know the person using the language.. it's *all* a guessing game in general. Only your client knows what they mean. I voted to close this as primarily opinion-based. Truth is, out of all users here YOU are the only one in a position to answer.

Comment: What are the consequences if you design, like, something *you* think is totally rad and out of here, down but hip with the crowd, and send it back? Do they get angry? Do they retract their jobs? Do they suggest concrete adjustments?

Comment: If they are inarticulate as your client seems, can you get them to link or point to something similar to what they're imagining?

Comment: It's important to interpret your clients instructions as best you can. If as a rule they give you brief instructions and refuse to elaborate then it is up to you to bring them likely solutions. I see Hollywood Sleek that's ballin as high fashion, high production values, it shouldn't look like a website but like an ad in a fashion magazine. The red carpet feel. Full screen images that are framed and exposed perfectly. Glamour, baby. Models, jewels and sports cars if appropriate. Sleek, to me here, means light on text. Ballin means cool. The whole thing geared to the younger generations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**They don't know either, so do what you like ;)**

From a client management point of view - and this might be contentious - I don't think it really means "anything" very much of consequence.

Well in fairness, taken along with "ballin'" I would guess they mean "Exciting, Glossy, American (let's not debate exactly what that would mean haha...let's go with, erm, "confident")

So if I were you I would do whatever I felt was right for the job, and then simply tell them that it's both "ballin'" and "pedal to the metal" or whatever other silly phrases come to mind. The point being that I dubt they know themselves what these things mean, and if handled correctly by a confident, and competent, designer they be told it's those things after the fact :)

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, I'm not a mind reader, but one of the definitions of *sleek* means: elegant/streamlined shape or design, I obviously have no idea if that is what they actually mean.  Another possibility is that "sleek" is a malapropism, perhaps they mean "Hollywood chic", as in "Hollywood style/fashion"??

As for "ballin" that's not even a word I recognise. Is it US slang perhaps?  I'm from the UK and have no idea what it means.

You could call them and explain that you can't do any work without a proper brief.  If they can't explain it in words, ask them for example websites with the graphic styles that they like. I often do that with clients who have no idea how to describe designs.

Comment: _Ballin’_ is indeed an Americanism; it just means ‘cool, awesome, amazing, brilliant, on fleek’ (just to be Twitter-inclusive).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "on fleek"?  You lost me with that one too!

Comment: It's all US slang Billy :)

Comment: That just mean you don’t spend enough time around teenagers on Twitter. Sorry, did I say “not enough”? I meant “exactly the right amount of time”, of course.

Comment: A 51 year old man, spending time around teenagers online is not something I would feel comfortable with. LOL

Comment: Actually I'm only a couple years younger.. it's not the age.. it's the locale.... These have been around for 20 some-odd years in the US.

Comment: @Scott Surely not _on fleek_? That only really appeared a year or two ago, as far as I can remember.

Comment: @Scott - George Bernard Shaw is reputed to have said the UK and US are "two nations separated by the same language"

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet "On fleek" is from the 90s, maybe 00s :) You have your fair share over there too Billy... "fit", "Brov", "Blagged", "Pikey", getting "pissed"... just off the top of my head ;)

Comment: @Scott _Fleek_ is sporadically attested as a slang term with various unrelated meanings from the early noughties; but I cannot find any references for _on fleek_ before [Peaches Monroee randomly invented it in June 2014](http://www.newsweek.com/2015/03/27/meet-chicago-teen-behind-fleek-311031.html).

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Because everything on the internet is accurate, right? :) "Peaches" invented nothing, although she's credited for adding "on" for some reason.  Who knows how that happened. Trust me.. it was around in the 00's no one used fleek by itself. Everything was "on fleek" or you never heard the word fleek.

Comment: @Scott Probably she wasn’t the first to invent it (just like J.K. Rowling didn’t really _invent_ Hogwarts or Muggles, or like _laser_ has been in use since the 15th century), but there’s absolutely no doubt that prior to June 2014, _on fleek_ was obscure enough to only appear a handful of times on the Internet, whereas a month after Monroee’s Vine it appeared millions of times. It may have been in limited, localised use somewhere in the noughties, but it didn’t make an imprint if it was. _Fleek_ was definitely used alone (the sense ‘fake Gleek’ is the only one I recall, but there were others).

Comment: @Scott, oh yes, plenty of British words too with completely different meanings in US slang.  Just having some nice lamb *faggots* and some *spotted dick* for my *tea* - translation: lamb meatballs, steamed pudding with raisins, and dinner.